# Manually setting user bound properties

Tags: google-apps-script, editor, app-secret

I am working on a script, which needs to store a secret API key.
In the old editor, there was an option to set user properties directly from the UI of the editor (which was in meantime removed), and I do not see any similar option in the new one. I saw multiple answers detailing how to set them through the UI of the spreadsheet or other "finicky" way.
Is it possible to set that property through the Script UI directly?

Answer (score 1):

It is not available anymore in the new editor. I have 2 options in mind.

1. Switch to the legacy editor to set your properties using the Script UI.
2. You can use [**Properties Service**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) to store simple data in key-value pairs scoped to one script (Script Properties), one user of a script (User Properties), or one document (Document Properties).

---

[**Properties Service Methods:**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties#propertiesservice)

- [getDocumentProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getDocumentProperties()), Gets a property store (for this script only) that all users can access within the open document, spreadsheet, or form.
- [getScriptProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getScriptProperties()),   Gets a property store that all users can access, but only within this script.
- [getUserProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getUserProperties()), Gets a property store that only the current user can access, and only within this script.

---

### Example on how to create user properties key-value pair:

```
  // Sets several user properties, then retrieves them and logs them.
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperties({
    'cow': 'moo',
    'sheep': 'baa',
    'chicken': 'cluck'
  });

  var animalSounds = userProperties.getProperties();
  for (var kind in animalSounds) {
    Logger.log('A %s goes %s!', kind, animalSounds[kind]);
  }

  var keys = userProperties.getKeys();
  keys.forEach(key=>{
    Logger.log("Key: "+key+", Value: "+userProperties.getProperty(key));
  })
```

### Output:

[image]

---

### How it works:

1. When you get [PropertiesService.getUserProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getUserProperties()) it will return a [properties object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties) that acts as the interface to access your user properties
2. You can use [setProperties(properties)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setpropertiesproperties) to set your user specific key-value pair.
3. You can access your key-value pair using either [getProperty(key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#getpropertykey) or by [getProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#getproperties) as shown in the sample code.

---

### Test

I modified the script after adding user properties and run the code on 2 different users (owner and another user) to verify if user properties added will only be available to the user who created it.

**Code:**

```
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

  var keys = userProperties.getKeys();
  Logger.log(keys.length);
  keys.forEach(key=>{
    Logger.log("Key: "+key+", Value: "+userProperties.getProperty(key));
  })
```

**Owner Result:**

[image]

**Another User Result:**

[image]